# How do we know V in the SVD is the eigenvectors of M*M?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

if we have any real matrix M nXm,
the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (singular value decomposition) allows us to decompose it into $U{\Sigma}V^T$, where V is an orthogonal real matrix composed of the eigenvectors of $M^TM$.

from wikipedia, I know that:

[image]

which, to my understanding, should prove that the eigenvectors of $M^TM$ are the column of V in SVD.
but I feel like I am missing something - it seems to me like we never proved that V's vectors are eigenvectors, only that they fit the diagonalization format. but there might be a different, non-eigenvector matrix that when multiplied by a different, non-eigenvalue matrix and then by itself transposed gives M*M, right?

if so, we can use it for the SVD and it will still fit. which brings me to my question: **How do we know V in the SVD is the eigenvectors of M*M?**

Comment: Please define all objects in the order they are invented. What is the $A$ in the title and where is the question from the title to be located in the text? Please **always** ask the question in the text. (Not only in the title.) Please define the many letters $M,\Sigma,U,V$. If these are matrices in a finite dimensional vector space, then please mention this. If some Hilbert space is involved, please take time to define it (first) with its base field ($\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$). Please make sure that abbreviations are explained. (What is SVD?) The answerer will type more. Please give wiki links.

Comment: I improved the question, hope this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Here is a simple more general statement which should solve your doubt.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary (square) matrix, $V$ an invertible matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix such that $A=VDV^{-1}$. Then the columns of $V$ are all the eigenvectors of $A$ and the diagonal entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues.

*Proof*: just rewrite the equation slightly to get $AV=VD$, and then consider a single column $v_i$ of $v$ to get $Av_i=D_{ii}v_i$. $\square$

Note:

- In the general case, the columns of $V$ are neither orthogonal, nor normalized.
- But in the SVD case, $V$ is orthogonal (or unitary in the complex case), thus $V^{-1}=V^*$, and the columns are all nicely orthonormal.